# How to communicate between two different domains through javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, popup, cross-domain

I am building an embedded chat control with javascript, ajax, and signalr. Users can add it into their websites by adding a bit of javascript that calls back to our servers and requests the javascript needed to build the chat widget. The chat widget is then embedded on their website, but it can be popped out into a new window. The new window is from our server, no longer on their site.

The Task:
When user closes the popup I need to re-show the embedded popup and resume the chat as normal.

The Problem:
The popup chat is on a different domain (our site) than the embedded chat (their site).

What I have tried:

1) Give the window opening up the popup a function to reset. OnUnload of the pop-out window call window.opener.reset() <--- window.opener gets accessed denied due to cross domain security issues.

2) When popping up the window, start a loop to check local storage. onUnload of the pop-out window set a variable in the browser localstorage. <---- localstorage did not seem to go through cross domains either. I could not see the change even though the code hit.

3) Same as 2) but using browser cookies instead <--- same situation as 2) it does not go across domains.

What I have to work with:

- Central server and database.
- Javascript running on their site.
- Embedded Chat on their site that can pop up a
  chat window that runs on our site but continues the same chat
  session.
- Chat session can be started either in the embedded chat
  widget or in the popup and should be able to go back and forth
  between the two easily.

Comment: Iframes are going to be the way to go. However, two-way communication through an iframe could get VERY messy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, we cannot create a popup page that contains our chat widget within an iFrame because we cannot add any pages to their site. All we can have them do is add the little bit of javascript to their homepage that embeds the original chat widget; which is why the popup window uses our site to host the chat.

Comment: Interesting. What about creating a public API while using sockets?

Without sockets, you COULD implement the chat the way it was in the old days by polling with http requests every so often using setInterval -- like every 100ms -- on both clients to check and see if a new message has been created, if so it adds it to the chat list.

Comment: Problem with that one is the user can popup the chat window before they even start the chat. The embedded chat window would have no way of knowing what chatID to connect to. And I would be a little worried about constantly pulling the site for every user when our websites could have thousands of users at a time.

Comment: Do not add unrealated tags!

Comment: Sorry, i was working with an embedded chat on the external domain...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution probably is to use postMessage.

What you would have to do is the following. Let the user insert this content on his page:

```
// open your popup chat
var popup = window.open(yourpopup);
popup.postMessage("init",
                  "https://tagetUrl.com");


function receiveMessage(event)
{
  if (event.origin !== "http://YOURDOMAIN.org")
    return;
  // initialize your chat again
}
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

In your PopUp you then would have to do something like this:

```
source = null;
origin = null;
function receiveMessage(event)
{
  source = event.source;
  origin = event.origin;
}
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

When the PopUp closed ( onUnload ) you can send a message back to the original page:

```
source.postMessage("closed", origin);
```

I hope i could help.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am going to give postMessage a shot and see if i can work with that. I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: I just updated my answer cause it looked a little bit messy. I hope its also more useful for you to also solve the problem to get the source window in the popup. Good luck!